# Disable Active Noise Cancelling on Powerbeats3

Tags: macos, bluetooth

From my experience, it seems like Powerbeats3 uses some kind of Active Noise Cancelling, but I can't find it documented.

How can I disable it if that's the case? It's paired to my 2017 MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powerbeats3 do not have active noise cancellation.

They only have passive noise cancellation and there's been no published plans to add ANC to them in the future.

There's nothing for you to enable/disable for these headphones.